# PHP error/ exception handling library (Python would be nice too)

Tags: php, debugging

I am looking for a free for commercial use PHP library to help me with error handling.

Ideally (but not a “must”), it should hook error and exception handling, so that I just add one line of code to kick it off.

It would be nice if I could override it in a few places, but continue to have it as the default handler. Possibly just `off()` and `on()` calls.

It should gather as much information as possible, and present it in a clear manner.  E.g file name, line number, error/exception info, stack dump, globals such as `$_POST[]`, `$_GET[]`, etc, local variables if that is possible, and the kitchen sink.

It should be possible to control how the information is presented. For instance, during development, I might want to see it in the browser (or its developer console). In production, I would probably want it to email me, and possibly inform the user that a problem has occurred and is being handled, maybe providing a link with more info.

---

[Update] I would also like [something similar for Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/234313/handling-exceptions-in-python-3). My current exception handler looks like this (not any more it doesn't; see the link just before):

```
# +=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=+=
except KeyboardInterrupt as e: # Ctrl-C
    raise e
except SystemExit as e: # sys.exit()
    raise e
except Exception as e :
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    scriptName = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    functionName = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name
    print('=======================================================================================================')
    print('Unhandled exception: ', exc_type, scriptName, 'at line', exc_tb.tb_lineno)
    print('                      in function', functionName)
    print('                     ', str(e))

    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: I can't believe that there are no other PHP coders here. What do you use?

Comment: Coders are probably in stackoverflow.  Did you try the **try**,**catch**, and **throw** commands built in to php?

Comment: But software recommendations are off topic there :-)  There are enough if us here, too. Yes, I catch exceptions, also for some error conditions, I have a central error handler. I send myself en email with stack dump  & error details, but was looking for something more "professional". I found some stuf fon GitHib after posting this. See https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=php+error+handler&s=stars&type=Repositories